# Bold harpoons in math mode

Tags: bold

Is it possible to make the up/down harpoons bold? I tried `\boldmath`, `\boldsymbol` as well as `bm` package and they made no difference.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[thick,circle,draw,blue,minimum size=0.8cm] at (1,0) {$\boldsymbol{\upharpoonleft \downharpoonright}$};
%\node[thick,circle,draw,blue,minimum size=0.8cm] at (1,0) {$\bm{\upharpoonleft \downharpoonright}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$\boldsymbol{\upharpoonleft \downharpoonright}$` works (notice curly braces), but result is poor (man bold) ...

Comment: @Zarko Tried that and it made no difference on my system!? Missing braces was a typo, fixed

Comment: try to move `amssymb` before `bm` package: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[thick,circle,draw,blue,minimum size=0.8cm] {$\boldsymbol{\upharpoonleft\downharpoonright}$};
\node[thick,circle,draw,blue,minimum size=0.8cm] at (1,0) {$\bm{\upharpoonleft \downharpoonright}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Done here by manually overlaying 3 such non-bolded symbols in close proximity.  Original shown for comparison...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\boldupharpoonleft{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{-0.06ex}{c}{.00ex}{{\upharpoonleft}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{0.00ex}{c}{.07ex}{{\upharpoonleft}}{{\upharpoonleft}}%
}}}
\def\bolddownharpoonright{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{0.06ex}{c}{.00ex}{{\downharpoonright}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{0.00ex}{c}{-.07ex}{{\downharpoonright}}{{\downharpoonright}}%
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[thick,circle,draw,blue,minimum size=0.8cm] at (1,0) {$\color{blue}
  \boldupharpoonleft \bolddownharpoonright$};
\node[thick,circle,draw,blue,minimum size=0.8cm] at (2,0) {$
  \upharpoonleft \downharpoonright$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]